# need to decode '{"email":"dfsdfsd(fsdf\fsdf\fsdf).fsdfsd.fsd"}' json string in perl using JSON class

Tags: json

need to decode '{"email":"dfsdfsd(fsdf\fsdf\fsdf).fsdfsd.fsd"}' json string in perl using JSON class.
when i trying to do i am getting below output

$VAR1 = {
          'email' => 'dfsdfsd(fsdf
sdf
sdf).fsdfsd.fsd'
        };

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\f` using another `\` so it should be `\\f`.

So you string should be like this

```
'{"email":"dfsdfsd(fsdf\\fsdf\\fsdf).fsdfsd.fsd"}'
```